# How to know if there are any pending records to be updated in a store?

Tags: extjs5

I have a grid Panel where I am displaying number of records. There are 2 button, '`Update`' and '`Close`'. 
If we will click the '`close`' button, then it should see if there are any pending record, if yes then it should tell the user to finish it, 
if no then it will redirect to another URL.

In '`dockedItems`' there is a close button. In there I have to write the logic. I know, I have to use `isDirty()` function, but I need guidance how to use that.

```
{
                xtype : 'gridpanel',
                region: 'center',
                title : 'Search Results',
                id : 'searchResultsGrid',
                plugins: [{
                    ptype: 'cellediting',
                    listeners: {
                        beforeedit : function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                            console.log('beforeedit');
                        },
                        edit : function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                            console.log('edit');
                        },
                        canceledit : function (editor, context, eOpts) {
                            console.log('canceledit');
                        }
                    }
                }],
                columnLines : true,
                autoScroll  : true,
                selModel  : new Ext.selection.CheckboxModel({
                    checkOnly: true,
                    enableKeyNav: false,
                    allowDeselect: true,
                    deselectOnContainerClick: false
                }),
                border      : true,
                resizable   : true,
                columns : gridColumnList,              
                store : {
                    model : poModel,
                    proxy : new Ext.Hmhco.SFDCProxy({
                        sessionId: '{!$Api.Session_ID}',
                        model: poModel,
                        url: "https://" + location.hostname + "/services/data/v31.0/"
                    })
                },
                dockedItems: [{
                    xtype: 'toolbar',
                    items: [{
                        itemId: 'update',
                        text: 'Update',
                        handler: function(button, evt) {

                            var grid = Ext.getCmp('searchResultsGrid'),
                                ds = grid.getStore();

                            ds.sync({
                                success : function (batch, options) {
                                    console.log('Sync Success!');
                                },
                                failure : function (batch, options) {
                                    var errorList = [],
                                        exceptionList = batch.getExceptions();
                                    for (var i = 0; i < exceptionList.length; i++) {
                                        var err = exceptionList[i].getError();
                                        errorList.push({
                                            url: err.request.getUrl()
                                        });
                                    }
                                    exceptionList = 1;
                                    console.dir(errorList);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    },'-', {
                        itemId: 'close',
                        text: 'Close',
                        handler: function(button, evt) {
                            // TO DO : It should  see if there are pending updates (store.isDirty()) and confirm the close with the user via an Ext.Msg method.                                                                 
                        }
                    }]
                }],  // dockedItems
            }],
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `isDirty` will be any helpful here. IMO the best choice here is to use `Ext.Data.Store.getModifiedRecords()` and `Ext.Data.Store.getRemovedRecords()`. If any of this functions returns non-empty array it means you have some pending records to be updated.